# how do i debug PHP Image with print?

Tags: php, image, debugging

i want to debug an php generated image algorithm with print.
The problem is that it doesn't output the text i put in print.
How can i output variables, so that i can debug?
Thanks,
Furtano

```
 public function drawPicture()
    {
        $im = imagecolorallocate ($this->picture, 255, 0, 255);
        imagettftext($this->picture, $this->fontSize , 0, 100, 100,$im , "cooperm.TTF", $this->name);



        # int ImageCopy ( resource $dst_im , resource $src_im , int $dst_x , int $dst_y , int $src_x , int $src_y , int $src_w , int $src_h )
        //imagecopy($this->picture, $this->pika, $this->wappen['pika']['dst_x'], $this->wappen['pika']['dst_y'], 0, 0, $this->pika_size[0], $this->pika_size[1]);

        $zufall = rand(1,99999999);

        #header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
        imagepng($this->picture);

        $this->checkFontSize();

        imagedestroy($this->picture);

        print "WHY_DOESNT_PRINT?";


    }
```

Comment: Turn error reporting on. It's possible your script is failing silently before the `print` statement. Try moving the `print` further up your code, even to the beginning of the function to make sure it's being called.

Comment: the script doesnt fail. thats how i use the script print '<img src="schild.php?text=christian">';

Comment: what do you see now? considering that you commented out the call to the header function but you are still calling imagepng you should see the image source and your text after it

Comment: i only see the image and the text doesnt come after i put it after imagepng(), if i use imagejpeg() instead it puts the text right Oo

Comment: If you can not see the image and the text is that you are sending image headers somewhere in your code. Make sure you are not sending the header image in another point in your code.

Comment: Related: [PHP invalid image's and error handling](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2574713/367456)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending a .png image to the browser, so the browser tries to display an image. The additional text is just seen as invalid image data and thus not displayed.

A solution to your problem would be using `header()` calls to send debug messages to your browser, or use Firefox+Firebug+ a PHP firebug adapter. Firebug works with headers to transmit information, so it's safe in image generation functions.

Answer (score 0):

To debug using rorrorlog the point that the script that you want to see.
The written files can be easily viewable.

Es:

```
error_log("\r\n debug " . implode("; ", $hc), 3, "errors.log"); // in case array
error_log("\r\n print " . $im, 3, "errors.log");
```